# Ajuda com API do google maps + banco de dados

Tags: google-maps, jsp

Boa tarde galera, estou fazendo meu TCC utilizando a api do google maps e achei um tópico aqui muito bom: 
[Como Fazer Icone andar na api Google Maps](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125272/como-fazer-icone-andar-na-api-google-maps)

Onde é explicado como se faz para "andar" com o marcador no mapa e dar um efeito de movimentação ao vivo.

Esse tópico me ajudou bastante, porém ele está utilizando de um array estático para fazer a movimentação do marcador, gostaria de fazer exatamente o que está no tópico citado, porém puxando as coordenadas do banco de dados e deixando isso em loop, sempre puxar a coordenada do BD e atualizar no mapa.

Comment: Você precisa atualizar o mapa de acordo com espaço de tempo X da sua aplicação.